# How to string with quotes in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

```
my $search = "Sony's";
my $string = "in TV sony's walkman";
```

how can i get a match of "`sony's`" in `$string` using regular expression.

Answer (score 6):

```
my $search = "Sony's";
my $string = "in TV sony's walkman";

$string =~ /$search/;   # does not match
$string =~ /$search/i;  # matches case-insensitive
```

This is a total beginner question. Please first [learn the language](http://learn.perl.org/), [read a book or two](http://books.perl.org/).

Comment: there is no problem with the quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Since you require a case-insensitive match, use the `i` modifier:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $search = "Sony's";
my $string = "in TV sony's walkman";

if ( my ($match) = $string =~ /($search)/i ) {
    print "Matched string: $match";
}
```

Please read: [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

Comment: can matched my ($match) = $string =~ /($search1|$search2|$search3)/i ?

Comment: You will have to replace `$match` with an array such as `@matches` and will have to add the `g` modifier in addition to the `i` to make it `gi` and match globally.